# Flexbox images in IE showing full image height instead of auto

Tags: flexbox, height, internet-explorer-11

I'm using flexbox for vertical centering on the link below but in IE 11 the images are stretching to the full height of the original image and not "auto" like it should be displaying based on the relation to the 100% width in the fluid container. It shows the normal proportionate height in Safari, Chrome and Firefox.

Does anyone know what I need to add or modify to my css or the HTML to get these to show normally in IE? In case it matters, I also have an equal heights column WP plugin that applies the inline height CSS using the largest height of these div selectors.

Thanks in advance for any help. My code below:

https://www.indexarsolutions.com/apps/

```
.apps .pic, .apps .text { 
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;
}

<div class="su-row apps">
  <div class="su-column su-column-size-1-3">
    <div class="su-column-inner su-clearfix">
     <div class="pic">
      <img class="alignleft wp-image-1550" src="https://www.indexarsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/Facility-Example-photo.jpg" alt="" width="371" height="247" />
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="su-column su-column-size-2-3">
    <div class="su-column-inner su-clearfix">
     <div class="text">An industrial marketing AR app helps a client’s globally distributed customer base visualize and explore a 500 acre, billion-dollar facility virtually. The app eliminates the need for 80-slide sales presentations or costly and time consuming on-site visits.</div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have some inline height set on the element "height: 1536px;", seems you can fix the issue with the inline height property and add display: inline-block to the element also

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was aware that the height property would possibly fix it in IE but I was trying to go this route for dynamic heights and that inline height was set by that Equal Heights Column plugin, which was determining the max height value for any element with either selector (.apps .pic, .apps .text) and making each element with that selector that height. I was using that in conjunction with the CSS listed above to get everything vertical centered but for some reason IE 11 was showing the inline height as 1536 while other browsers were rendering the correct 247px height.

Comment: For a temp fix on that link I have since just removed those selectors from that Equal heights plugin and set the height property of 246px in my style sheet for those elements. Also added "inline-block" but not sure if that's needed since I set the actual height.......... So I guess my question is, if I don't know what the height values are going to be for a group of elements (including images) and I want to vertically center everything (text next to image), how do I prevent this stretching of images in IE 11??? Thanks again!

Comment: If you provide a working code snippet _within the question_, reproducing the issue, you most likely will get a proper answer. Only external links is not good enough, as when that link die, so does the value of this question and its answers.